# What is the name of the inlaid pins in this FPC flat cable?

Tags: connector

I discovered that this flat cable is of type FPC - 2.54mm pitch, but I had no success searching the inland pins.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the name of the inlaid pins in this FPC flat cable?

"FFC, FPC (Flat Flexible) Connector Contacts"

> I had no success searching the inland pins.

You can buy the contacts here.

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connectors/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connector-contacts/344

But just having the contacts won't do you much good without the machine to install them.

You know you can buy the flat cable with the contacts already installed, right?

Or, you can buy flextrips with solder tabs at both ends: https://www.digikey.com/short/4qrdjqmf